# Set a field based on another filed in Formik based on an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have two input fields. I want to update one field based on another field and I am using Formik. When i type in address field it sets it into input state and calls handleChange
and finds the pincode and logs it. But it is coming wrong as it is supposed to change whenever we type but it just sets the finds it for the first letter. Lets say for "h" 560102 and even though we type "hosurRoad" the pincode doesn't change. Also how do i update another field pincode with this value.

```
export const SignupForm = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const recoganizedAreas = {
    'hsr':'560102',
    'bypanahalli':'676667',
    'marathalli':'667776',
    'hosurRoad':'321236',
    'teachersColony':'560101'
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleChange = () => {
      const foundArea = Object.keys(recoganizedAreas).find(key => key.includes(input))
  
      const foundPinCode = recoganizedAreas[foundArea] || "Not found";
      console.log(foundPinCode);
    }
  },[input]);
   
  
    
  return (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
          <div className={classes.formWrapper}>

            <Formik
              initialValues={{address:'',pincode:''}}
              onSubmit={values => {
                console.log(values);
              }}
            >
            {props => {
              const {
                values,
                handleChange,
                setFieldValue
              } = props;
              return (
                <Form>
                  <Grid container spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Typography>
                          Your details
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>

                      <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Textfield
                          name="address"
                          label="Address"
                          value = {values.address}
                        />
                      </Grid>

                      <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Textfield
                          name="pincode"
                          label="Pincode"
                          value={values.pincode}
                        />
                  {setInput(values.address)}
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Button>
                          Submit Form
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Form>
              )}}
            </Formik>

          </div>
        </Container>
  );
};
```